# Django exporting datetime to csv file

Tags: django, csv, datetime

I am rendering a queryset to a template and csv.

```
models.One2OneInfoLog.objects.filter(one_2_one_info=pk).values_list(Lower('name'), 'location', 'created').order_by('created')
```

in the template view I get a created value: 16-06-2021, 10:58
in csv file I get: 2021-06-16 08:58:27.780570+00:00

It seems its writing the timestamp in the csv file by deducting 2 hours. Is their some way to correct it? And can I change the formatting to match the template view.

Comment: This might be due to timezone diferences. The datetime is shown in UTC time, whereas you entered it probably in CET which is 2 hours ahead during the summer, and 1 hour ahead in the winter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a time zone issue. The data storage saves times in UTC time. More information on setting up time zones can be found in the docs for Django [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/timezones/)

> Time zone support is disabled by default. To enable it, set USE_TZ =
> True in your settings file. By default, time zone support uses pytz,
> which is installed when you install Django; Django also supports the
> use of other time zone implementations like zoneinfo by passing tzinfo
> objects directly to functions in django.utils.timezone.

Comment: It is still outputting UTC time to the CVS. I would like it to output CET as it does on my website.